# JavaScript not loading?

Tags: javascript, html, menu

FIX: I linked to the wrong script, very sorry for this.

I have my script file linked correctly (at least I think so). Here's the link:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/menu.js"></script>
```

This link is right before the closing body tag. I have tried placing this link in the head section but that doesn't help.

Here is the JS code that's in that script file:

```
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>title</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

    -Content-

        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/menu.js"></script>

    </body>
```

This script is for my push right menu on my website.

Any help, thanks! :D

UPDATE: I have added an alert into the script and that works but my menu still doesn't work?

Menu HTML:

```
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Please check browser console and tell me do you have any 404 error?

Comment: You can add after the closing of the body tag, not that it will fix but it's a good practice. You should put an `alert()` on the beggining of the script just for testing purposes, perhaps it's not loading due to wrong link.

Comment: Loads the browser the script file?
Open therefor the developer tool of your browser and check net "network" tab.

Comment: The `CSS file` has loaded?

Comment: do not put your scripts after the body tag, that is incorrect (@PhiterFernandes) best practice is to put it before the closing body tag. Also, you're including jQuery, why not use it?

Comment: No 404 error and I've changed the path to "../JR-Project/assets/js/menu.js" but no luck. the css loads perfectly @Mehdi Dehghani

Comment: removed that just now @Pamblam since I wanna try  pure JS

Comment: Check your browser setting & make sure the js is enabled

Comment: Updated OP, alerts work but menu still doesnt open? @Mehdi Dehghani

Comment: So, we need to see the HTML of the menu, I think

Comment: Updated the post with the HTML for the menu :D @Mehdi Dehghani

Comment: I just don't know, you linked `jQuery`, but why you wrote `pure js`?

Comment: Im still new to JS and want to learn it more before I move onto jQuery etc. @Mehdi Dehghani

Comment: I suggest put breakpoints in your callback and learn to debug

Comment: I thinks this is not great way to learn js, because js is more than working with `DOM`, left working with DOM to jQuery, anyway where is `dropdown-content`?

Comment: if you're just learning you relly should stick to jQuery.

Comment: check your source destination...or try to place your js in your main folder with html and check if it will work

Comment: Fixed, simple mistake too. Thank you everyone!

Comment: what was the mistake?

Comment: I've updated the OP with the mistake :) @Aris Constantinou

Answer (score 0):

different browsers handle events differently. this is why you should use jQuery because it takes care of all the differences for you. This function should do it for you in plain JS..

```
function on(elem,eventType,handler){
    if (elem.addEventListener){
        elem.addEventListener (eventType,handler,false);
     }else if (elem.attachEvent){
        elem.attachEvent ('on'+eventType,handler);
    }
}

on(window, "click", function(e){
    // .. do stuff
});
```